# How to get string between starting text and ending character using regular expression?

Tags: c#, regex

I want to get string starting with *color="* and *ending double quote* with parentheses () and with or without parameter, sometimes there may be many quoted words in a line. I want to select only matching start word and ending quote.

This is my input file

```
color="functions.getcolor('someinput')"
color="getcolor()"
color="!model.type && functions.getcolor(model.type, cofig.value)"
color="model.type == enums.someenum"
color="(something=something)||(Something=somethingelse)"
color="model.type" mode="getmode()"
```

This my regular expression

```
color=\".+\(.+\)*\"$
```

My current output is all line get selected except line 4 in input file
but my requirement is lines similar to first 3 lines of text get selected.

**Expected result**

```
color="functions.getcolor('someinput')"
color="getcolor()"
color="!model.type && functions.getcolor(model.type, cofig.value)"
```

How to write the regular expression for this?

Comment: Do you want to find all lines where there is a call to `getcolor(....)`?

Comment: Other than adding `^` at the beginning of the regex (to ensure `color=" is at the start), it does exactly what you describe.

Comment: @Archer simply adding `^` doesn't make the regex produce only the 3 expected results the op mentions. I think when I tested it yesterday it fixed one of them though?

Comment: @w00ngy It does what he describes.  The question was unclear.

Comment: @Archer agreed, I was a little confused by the question too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like within quotes, you want to be able to find text that has some kind of function call.  If this is the case, this regex will match lines 1-3 but not 4-6.  You can keep expanding the characters allowed within the [ ] if you encounter more.

[Example with Tests](https://regex101.com/r/qQ2dE4/309)

```
^color=\"([a-zA-Z.! &])+\(.+\)*\"$
```

Comment: If you can figure out the expression to invert this and use exclusions `[^ ... ]` instead of inclusions `[a-zA-Z.! &]`, it would be more manageable.